# NodeJS on Port 80 Randomly Stops Working

Tags: node.js

I recently began working on a small Node website on my computer, and it has been running fine for a few days on port 80. I am able to connect to localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.2 (my network IP address) and my public IP address (I have port forwarded) I restarted my computer, ran the program from console with Admin permissions and now when I connect to 192.168.1.2, or my public IP address, Chrome gives me the error: "No webpage was found for the web address: http://192.168.1.2/" IISNode is an alternative, but I have had lots of trouble setting it up. Netstat indicates port 80 is not blocked, and I have removed the default website from IIS. Port 80 is open on [YouGetSignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). Express is started on `var server = app.listen(80, "0.0.0.0");` I have restarted my computer a few more times. All of my research has yielded nothing. What could be going on?

Comment: it may be a dumb question, but did you check for IP changes just in case and if the port forward settings have maybe got reseted?

Comment: I did, port forward settings changes and IP changes have not occured.

Comment: Try searching Super User and Server Fault for port 80 problems, this sounds like a system/network issue and not a Node issue (primarily because it worked before and the code didn't change from that point)

Comment: Check your logs, it’s very possible you aren’t handling an error properly and it’s crashing or stalling the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Command Prompt in Admin, is issued `netstat -aon | find ":80"` and there was a process using port 80. I then issued `Taskkill /PID <YOUR PID> /F` because the process didn't show on task manager. The issue was then resolved.